# RecyclerView shows wrong image after fast scroll

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

In my application I'm using `RecyclerView.Adapter` with my custom `Holder` class. Each item consist of few `TextView`'s and one `ImageView`(icon). Problem is that `RecyclerView` shows wrong Image after fast scrolling.

Example:

[truth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AbX1.png)

[NOT truth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS2EL.png)

So, my holder is:

```
public class CafeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {
TextView itemName, itemType, itemMarksCount, itemCommentsCount, itemRating;
ImageView imgCafe;
ImageLoader imgLoader;
private Context context;
private int cafeId;

public CafeHolder(View view, Context context){
    super(view);
    this.context = context;
    itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCafeName);
    imgCafe = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgCafe);
    itemType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCafeType);
    itemMarksCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMarksCount);
    itemCommentsCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentsCount);
    itemRating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRatingCount);
    imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, InfoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(CafeDomain.ID, cafeId);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public void setCafeId(int cafeId){
    this.cafeId = cafeId;
}
```

And my RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
public class CafeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CafeHolder> {
private Context context;
List<CafeDomain> listItems;

public CafeAdapter(List<CafeDomain> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CafeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_cafe_item2, parent, false);
    CafeHolder vh = new CafeHolder(v, context);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CafeHolder holder, int position) {
    CafeDomain dItem =  this.listItems.get(position);
    holder.imgCafe.setImageDrawable(null);
    holder.itemName.setText(dItem.getName());
    ArrayList<TypeDomain> types = dItem.getTypes();
    StringBuilder sbTypes = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < types.size(); i++){
      sbTypes.append(types.get(i).getName());
      if (i!=types.size()-1)
          sbTypes.append(", ");  
    }
    holder.itemType.setText(sbTypes.toString());
    if (!dItem.getIconUrl().isEmpty()){
        holder.imgLoader.DisplayImage(dItem.getIconUrl(), holder.imgCafe); //load image from cache or web
    }
    else{
        holder.imgCafe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon200); //set default image
    }


    holder.itemMarksCount.setText(String.valueOf(dItem.getMarksCount()));
    holder.itemCommentsCount.setText(String.valueOf(dItem.getCommentsCount()));
    holder.itemRating.setText(String.valueOf(dItem.getRating()));
    holder.setCafeId(listItems.get(position).getId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

}
```

I can see, that this code:

```
else{
        holder.imgCafe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon200); //set default image
    }
```

is working, but two images are wrong anyway :(

UPDATE:
The problem is only when you fast scrolling list without image cache in disk. When we have cache, there is no problem here...

Comment: I recommend you using Universal Image Loader for this type of problems..!!

Comment: ok thanks for advice, I'll try it

Comment: @jankigadhiya I've tested, the same thing here... 
So the problem is not in ImageLoader class.
But! The problem is only when you fast scrolling list without image cached in disk. 
When we have cache, there is no problem here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi i think your problem is here:

```
 if (!dItem.getIconUrl().isEmpty()){
        holder.imgLoader.DisplayImage(dItem.getIconUrl(), holder.imgCafe); //load image from cache or web
    }
    else{
        holder.imgCafe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon200); //set default image
    }
```

I can offer you two solutions that may work. First check your imageUrl is null with `TextUtils.isEmpty()`

```
 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dItem.getIconUrl())){
        holder.imgLoader.DisplayImage(dItem.getIconUrl(), holder.imgCafe); 
    }
    else{
        holder.imgCafe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon200); //set default image
    }
```

İf this does not work, if you can set a image drawable for `empty url` or `url loading fail` just leave it to your image downloader and just use the code below:

```
holder.imgLoader.DisplayImage(dItem.getIconUrl(), holder.imgCafe);
```

Comment: dItem.getIconUrl() returns empty string("") if cafe has no icon.
Second solution fixed my problem, now I just have to add simple check url in my ImageLoader class.
Thanks!

Comment: i'm glad that it helped you.